# How to stop sending RST to specific IP

Tags: macos, ipfw

I want to stop sending RST to specific IP(192.168.56.101) on Mac OS X.

I enter this command. But it still send RST.

```
sudo ipfw add drop tcp from 192.168.56.1 to 192.168.56.101 in tcpflags rst
```

What do I change this command?

Comment: Unfortunately you don't give any background info, but it seems you are trying to solve the wrong problem. If the system sends a RST packet, the socket which was used will be closed, thus allow no further communication. IMHO it would be better to check the application for errors and see *why* it sends an RST segment.

Comment: I want not to send rst packet when system receive syn ack packet.

Comment: So why not prevent the SYN/ACK packet from coming into the system at all? This is basic configuration on all firewalls.

Comment: I try manual 3way handshake with scapy. System send rst packet before ack packet is sent.

Answer (score 2):

Thx for your clues.Finally,I got there.

first.add this line to /etc/pf.conf

```
block drop proto tcp from 172.31.82.98 to 103.214.68.23 flags R/R
```

then load the pf rules with

```
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

then enable the pf rules with

```
sudo pfctl -e
```